# Cross compatible CSS (positioning)?

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a site: http://www.quass.com/erase.php

Position of the flash widget is fine in Firefox but not in IE8

What's the reason? How to fix it?

Comment: Only 100 errors and 46 warnings in W3C validator. And you say IE8 complains? Strange ...

Answer (score 3):

You don't define `DOCTYPE` so the page is rendered in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). So you need to use a proper `DOCTYPE`. [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.2) you can find what is `DOCTYPE` and what are the options you have. You must add it in the top of your html document. If you want to use html5 the DOCTYPE is still needed, so you have to use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. Then, whatever is your `DOCTYPE` choice, you can validate your web page with the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 2):

As answered by reiso up here, you have a malformed HTML problem. And while Firefox doesn't bother that much, IE8 is a bit pricky in this.
Check your source, close all `<div>`s tags before starting another `<div>`, if you make the html well-written and standard-compliant I'm 100% sure everything will work as you wish :)

Once I had the very same problem, and guess what? it was just a `<div>` tag not closed that caused IE to mess around with everything.

Comment: All browsers are pricky about this.  IE is actually traditionally much less strict about it, it just doesn't attempt to match other browsers' renderings while it's at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is [malformed](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.quass.com%2Ferase.php).  Most specifically you are missing a doctype declaration.  `<!doctype html>` is a decent choice for starters — there should be absolutely no characters before it in your source.

Comment: @Sarfraz please tell me you are above competitive downvoting -_-

Comment: This answer is just wrong and obsolete. HTML5 introduced an "unnamed" doctype declaration. **Edit:** He does not seem to be sure about his source.. However, my complain still is valid :)

Comment: HTML5 requires a doctype declaration (http://w3.org/tr/html5/syntax.html#syntax-doctype), and even if it didn't, the necessity for a doctype declaration has little to do with specifications and much to do with vendor implementations.

Comment: @Matt: You could have made the same comment in my answer pointing to reisio for down voting me without any explanation. Why the biased thinking...

Comment: @Sarfraz - My thinking is not biased. Like @reisio, I believe it is better to 1) correct invalid HTML and 2) use a doctype to enable standards mode BEFORE even thinking about resorting to conditional comments. Your advice was very poor indeed.

Comment: @Sarfraz: I added my answer and was typing up a comment for you.  I downvoted first because I wanted it to be clear that your answer was bad advice in the interim.

Comment: @Matt: Not poor as far as I am concerned and nothing prevents you from upvoting whoever you like !

Comment: @reisio: Your comment came after quite some time :)

Comment: @Sarfraz - apparently poor enough that you felt it necessary to delete it yourself. Despite your reputation score, nobody is correct all the time. Let it go.

Comment: @Matt: As you think, no worries, have fun :)

Comment: No reason to discuss it too much guys, we all try to help and for this reason this community is great :)